# Installed as a dual boot ubuntu 13.04 alongside win8 and no grub?

Tags: 13.04, grub2, windows-8

i previously had windows 7 on my machine when i bought it i installed win8 now but i wanted to try out ubuntu so i installed alongside win8 but there was no grub screen to choose ubuntu.. if anyone knows of a way to fix this please let me know !! THANK YOU

Comment: If it doesn't work then let me know.

Comment: I had this problem before alot of times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot up a live cd that is the same version and bit as your Ubuntu OS. Use boot-repair to reinstall grub. Here is how first open up a terminal in put in this code.

**Installing boot-repair**

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

than

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

**Opening boot-repair**

```
sudo boot-repair
```

**Using boot-repair**

[image]

Then puss "Recommended repair" and before that, you need to make sure the default setting is right for your system, so just look over the Advanced options.

After you have done that reboot your computer and you will see grub again!

---

source : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score -1):

You could download EasyBCD for Windows, and add Grub2 to the Windows bootloader (only works for Vista or newer visions of Windows). You may have to manually specify which partition Grub2 is located on.

Comment: i have tried this method and i got a black screen when i try to boot into ubuntu

Comment: i have tried this method and i got a black screen when i try to boot into ubuntu it said "GRUB4DOS 0.4.5c 2012-06-19, mem:630k/511M/1016M, End: 3548A8 [Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word,TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device/filename. ] grub> _" i typed in boot and it says kernel needs to be loaded.

Comment: I should mention that I've just a little more detail to the post, which might be useful. The last sentence might be particularly useful.